# How to include gtk+ 4 as a dependency in python package setup file?

Tags: python, gtk, requirements.txt

**Background**

- I have used GTK+4 framework for a UI (my first time with GTK).
- While developing, I had installed the framework (GObject, etc) on my Fedora using the `dnf` package manager, [as instructed](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#fedora-getting-started).

**Problem**

How do I include GTK+ 4 (imported as `Gtk` and `Gdk` from `gi` in my python scripts) as a dependency in the `setup.cfg` (or `requirements.txt`)?

**Belief**

*subject to correction*

Since `pip` can't install GTK+4 framework, I can **never** include GTK+4 as a `pip` dependency for my project. I *must* provide [the link](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#fedora-getting-started) to install GTK+4 in some `INSTALL.md` instructions file. Won't this irritate the user? I can't simply tell them to `pip install <my-project>`.

Comment: Inspired by [this](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devguide/dev_environ.html#projects-with-pygobject-dependencies) cue, I'm leaving `pycairo` and `pygobject` as placeholders. Although, this is not the solution, since installation of GTK+4 system dependencies (referred in the OP) is a pre-requirement as stated at the top of that web-page.

Comment: I simply switched to PySide6 (Qt) instead.